# Puppeteer search element value

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I need to use a search input box for my code. I use puppeteer.
I tried to use a code that changes the element value and sets it to what I need to search, however it's like inspect element, it won't trigger any action on the search box.

The code I use at the moment is:

```
await page.$eval('input[class="INPUTSELECTOR]', el => el.value = 'russia');
```

I need a code that uses actual key pressing or copy-pasting something instead of setting it from the inspect element value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the type function.

```js
const input = await page.watForSelector('input[class="INPUTSELECTOR]');
await input.type('russia');
```